# About the problem related to first category (meager)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

We have $X$ an $F$-space, $Y$ a subspace of $X$ whose complement is of the first category. Prove that $Y=X$. This problem have a hint: need to show that $Y $ intersect $x+Y$  $\forall x \in X$, but i still don't know how do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first sentence led me to think you intended the topological meaning of "F-space", but then the mention of addition in the hint leads me to think that perhaps $F$ is supposed to be a field, $X$ a vector space over it, and $Y$ a vector subspace.

Comment: @Andreas: I suspect that [this notion of $F$-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-space) may be intended.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I agree with Brian M.Scott. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you show that $x+Y$ is co-meagre for each $x\in X$? If you can do that, you can use the fact that the union of two meagre sets is meagre to show that $Y\cap(x+Y)\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Can you explain for me how to use F-space in the hypothesis?

Comment: You need the fact that an $F$-space is a complete metric space in order to use the Baire category theorem, and you can use translation-invariance of the metric to show that $x+Y$ is co-meagre.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott. I have the last question, i can imagegine $x+Y$ intersect $Y$ $\forall x\in X$ imply $Y=X$, but how could write it clearly.

Comment: I was concentrating on why the hint is true and haven’t actually thought about how to use the hint. I’ll give it some thought and post if I come up with something.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott, I completely understand about this problem. The hint perhap come from Baire's theorem:

"If $S$ is either:
(a) a complete metric space, or

(b) a locally compact Hausdorff space,

then the intersection of every countable collection of dense open subsets of $S$ is dense in $S$"


Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that for every $x \in X$, $(x+Y) \cap Y \neq \emptyset$. Indeed, let us suppose that there exists $x \in X$ s.t. $x+Y \subset X \setminus Y$. Then $x+Y$ is of the first category, hence - since addition is a linear homeomorphism - $Y$ is of the first category. This is absurd, because we would have $X=Y \cup (X \setminus Y)$ so $X$ of the first category, absurd by Baire ($X$ is a complete metric space).

Now we have that for every $x \in X$ there exists $y \in Y \cap (x+Y)$, i.e. there exists $y'$ s.t. $y=x+y'$, hence $x=y-y' \in Y$ because $Y$ is a linear subspace. Then $X \subseteq Y$, which implies $X=Y$.